# Help with proof that $H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Edit: Prove that if $u,v \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ then $uv \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

My idea is to approximate with functions in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with compact support.

Let $u,v \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ there exists sequences $u_n,v_n \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$u_n \rightarrow u$ and $v_n \rightarrow v$ in $|| \cdot ||_{H^1} $. Now

$$ uv - u_n v_n = (u-u_n)v + u_n(v-v_n) \Rightarrow $$
$$ || uv - u_n v_n||_{H^1} = || (u-u_n)v + u_n(v-v_n)||_{H^1} \leq  $$
$$|| (u-u_n)v ||_{H^1} + ||u_n(v-v_n)||_{H^1} \rightarrow 0 \quad,\quad n \rightarrow \infty $$

Thus $u_n v_n \rightarrow uv$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since $u_n v_n \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}) $ the product $uv \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Feedback and corrections are appreciated!

Comment: Why does $\|(u -u_n)v\|_{H^1} \to 0$? You are assuming the product is in $H^1$, which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Okay, I see that.. But is it a good idea to try the approximation somehow?

Comment: Is it really true? If $u,v \in L^2(R)$ then $uv \in L^1(R)$ which is not a subset of $L^2(R)$.

Comment: I haven't really managed to sort it out yet, but i think it's true. I can include the question

Comment: It is clear to me that the statement cannot be generalized to any $H^1(R^n)$, as seen by studying singularities on the form $|x|^\alpha$ with $\alpha<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove that $uv\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, or equivalently, that $uv\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and there is $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$\int_\mathbb{R}(uv)\varphi'=-\int_\mathbb{R}g\varphi,\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}).\tag{1}$$

The first question is: does $uv\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$? The answer is yes, because $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

So, it remains to find some $g$, satisfying $(1)$ with $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Once weak derivatives are so closely related with standard derivatives, we may try as a first candidate for $g$, the function $uv'+u'v$. As in the previous paragraph, this function does belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now let $u_n,v_n\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $u_n,v_n\to u,v$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$. We have that $$\int_\mathbb{R}(u_nv_n)\varphi'=-\int_\mathbb{R} (u_nv_n'+u'_nv_n)\varphi,\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}). \tag{2}$$

To conclude, remember the fact that $H^1(\mathbb{R})\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is not only an inclusion, it is an continuous embedding, so by using similar inequalities as in your question, we can prove that in the limit, $(2)$ converge to $(1)$. I leave to you this calculation.

Comment: As noted on the comments of OP's question, the same result is not true for $N>1$, however, a sufficient condition for $uv\in H^1(\Omega)$, when $u,v\in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\Omega$ is an open set, is that $u,v\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.